# How can I extract volume and surface information from objects?

Tags: python, scripting

How can I extract volume and surface information from objects?

1. I create an objects (e.g. a monkey).
2. With a Python command how do I extract an object's information like: volume, surface, location etc.?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found that:

```
import bpy, bmesh
bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=True, rotation=True, scale=True)
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh( bpy.context.object.data )
ref_obj_name     = bpy.context.object.name
volume = float( bm.calc_volume() )
print(volume)
```

and zawardo for all...